# Keep android view in sync with server data

Tags: java, android, synchronization

I have a game that has an activity/view of open challenges. Challenges are opened by some user and can then be accepted by any other user. I expect that challenges are opened and accepted quite fast.

Then there is a problem with keeping the open challenges view in sync with the challenges on the server. I don't want to display challenges that are already accepted by another user. I know that it cannot be full real time, but what is the best thing to do in this situation?

At the moment challenges are loaded to the view from a REST server when the activity is created.

Comment: Will Android Push, C2DM solve your problem?

Comment: I think I will go for C2DM. It seems to be quite simple. If you write it in an answer I will accept it as the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Will Android Push, C2DM solve your problem? Here you will find [Google guys](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/push-applications-android.html) talking about C2DM

Answer (score 0):

Ever thought about using websockets?

I used it for a recent project to keep track of video state (when switching between devices e.g. phone to tablet or phone to tv etc).

You would keep an open connection while on your challenges screen.

Here is an Android implementation:
http://autobahn.ws/developers/tutorials/pubsub